# Error while doing jspm install using node 9

Tags: node.js, npm, jspm

Using node 9.4.0 and doing jspm install throwing below error.

```
warn Error on getOverride for jspm:npm
   TypeError: "timeout" must be an unsigned integer
     at validateTimeout (child_process.js:623:11)
     at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:202:3)
     at exports.exec (child_process.js:139:18)
```

node: 9.4.0
npm: 5.6.0
jspm: 0.16.55

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed and was related to the jspm-registry version which needs to be 0.4.4. Posted the issue in jspm github and solution is [here](https://github.com/jspm/npm/issues/176)